# Find a node in linked list and return index

Tags: java, linked-list

The below code is not returning the correct output for the following input 
*10 20 20 30 -1* for search element *40*(n=*40*).what is the logical error in code.

```
public class Solution {
    static int c=0; 
    public static int indexOfNRec(LinkedListNode<Integer> head, int n) {

        if(head.next==null )
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(head.next==null && head.data!=n)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(head.next==null && head.data==n)
            {

                return 0;
            }
        if(head.data==n)
        {
          return c;
        }
            c=c+1;
            indexOfNRec(head.next,n);
            return c; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Problems like this are easy to solve with a debugger. Invest a bit of time to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: it returns 3 @f1sh

Comment: Notice that the return value of the recursive call is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made this way harder than it needs to be. Try something like this:

```
public class Solution {
    public static int indexOfNRec(LinkedListNode<Integer> head, int n) {
        return solution(head, n, 0);
    }

    private static int solution(LinkedListNode<Integer> head, int searchFor, int index) {
        if(head == null )
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(head.data == searchFor)
        {
            return index;
        }
        return solution(head.next, searchFor, index + 1);
    } 
}
```

I presume your teacher told you the signature of the method to use. Note that it's really ugly to use static variables the way you did, as it won't work in a multi-threaded environment. Furthermore, because you don't ever clear them, it's a works-once solution. If you get called multiple times, you're going to get the wrong value after the first call.

So I kept your original method signature but chain it to a method that receives the index you're going to return. That eliminates the static variable, which makes your code reentrant -- thread-safe and usable more than once.

The method itself is very simple. Perform a null check and return on null. Otherwise if we found the data, great. Return. If not, recurse.

This is an important pattern to understand. Please make sure you know what it's doing, and make sure you test with a variety of values. I have NOT run this through a compiler, so there might be mistakes. But at least you can see the direction I was going.

Comment: why is my code is not checking the condition `head==null`?

Comment: @Depanshu I don't know, but you'll see it's the first thing my code does.